# How to add a has_many that exists or adding new on the spot to a model in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a rails form (attached image)  Where I want the user to create a group, and if they want right then and there create a location for a group and attach it (a location is really a group_id and an address).  Or select a location already created.  Trouble is I am not sure where to start looking to figure out how to hook that up.  Here is what the form looks like:

[image]

See the group locations?  I want it to be able to click the `add new` on there and then do one of two things depending upon what is most accepted in rails land:

A) somehow whisk a user away to the add new address for the address model/view (but knowing that when its created its also attached to the group being created here).
B) Pop up a modal dialog (yes lots of js and there are libs out there I think to help) that has the right form stuff, which would be just another fields_for?  or no?  in either case... I want it to be where if there are already some locations and they double click on that it would just use the already made ones.

I think option A) is easiest but no idea how the routes would handle going to a _form.html.erb file for the addresses while knowing it should be added to a group.

Attached is the group model (and I will have to do this rigmarole for **Providers** and **billing companies** too, though those forms are far more complex).
(Group and address are linked via a join table called GroupLocations:)

GroupLocation.rb

```
class GroupLocation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :provider_locations

end
```

Group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

    #I have to figure out how providers will be held in this app if its going to be an intermediary table or what.  Does deleting a provider from a group remove them
    #from the db all together or just that group?

    #validations
    validates :group_name, presence: true


    #associations

    #i think my issue is here, I have a lot of providers through provider_locations but there is no way to tell a group that provider_locations and group_locations are linked.
    has_many :group_locations
    has_many :providers, through: :provider_locations
    has_many :provider_locations, through: :group_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_and_belongs_to_many :billings
    has_many :addresses, through: :group_locations



    belongs_to  :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
    belongs_to  :mailing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'mailing_address_id'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :insurances
    #has_many :provider_locations, through: :group_locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailing_address


end
```

Address.rb:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_locations
    has_many :billings
end
```

One thing of note too, is the providers are vastly more complex in adding.  They are adding to a group location and that is how they are associated with a group:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :group_locations, through: :provider_locations
    has_many :groups, through: :group_locations 
    belongs_to :designation
    belongs_to :specialty
    #has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :invoices

end

class ProviderLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider  
  belongs_to :group_location

end
```

Comment: Did you take a look at nested_form gem? https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: I was doing the nested forms just fine using the mailing_address and billing_address and fields_for.  I thought the location was a bit different beast.  So I wasn't sure the right approach.   Same with the providers, as they are pretty complex.   I wish I could just goto address add new and know it belongs to that group and when created create a grouplocation join entry as well automagically.

Comment: If you want to add it to a group then the group would need to be persisted (this way you can create an appropriate route) or you would have to use nesting to handle this. If you want the user to be able to add multiple new addresses I would recommend looking at something like `cocoon` for this.

Comment: I will check out cocoon. For adding these things and getting a prototype done should I just for now seperate it and create a view somehow attached to the join? Where I can just say this address is this group and voila you have a group location.  Kinda like drag and droppy...